# Where to set @keyframes animations for optimal use?

Tags: css, optimization

Does it matter if the **@keyframes** rule is set before or after calling it? Since **CSS** stands for **Cascading Style Sheets**, isn't it logical to create them on the top of the file.css and call them after that?

Comment: You can define in any place in file no problem but even css transformation can be expensive.

Comment: It does not matter, and that is not what the “cascading” part means to begin with.